# is it possible to make service that work for a long time

Tags: java, android, service

is it possible to make service that work for a long time

after research a lot i can't find a good result. i want to create service that work for a long time but after i closes my app, the services going to destroy.what cam i do?

i tried never ending background service but it's not helpful

https://ibb.co/pnXnRVm

the link above show some application service that worked for long time e.g 121 hour

Answer (score 1):

You could run a `ForegroundService`, a `ForegroundService` is a high priority service, so it won't be killed until absolutely necessary. [Official docs reference](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground)

You can keep the foreground service running even when the app is killed by returning `START_STICKY` in `onStartCommand`.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i("LocalService", "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);
    // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
    // stopped, so return sticky.
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

> **START_STICKY**
>
> Constant to return from `onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)`: if this service's process is killed while it is started (after returning from `onStartCommand(Intent, int, int))`, then leave it in the started state but don't retain this delivered intent. Later the system will try to re-create the service. Because it is in the started state, it will guarantee to call `onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)` after creating the new service instance; if there are not any pending start commands to be delivered to the service, it will be called with a null intent object, so you must take care to check for this.
>
> This mode makes sense for things that will be explicitly started and stopped to run for arbitrary periods of time, such as a service performing background music playback.